# Integrate custom annotations in Zend Framework and Doctrine project

Tags: zend-framework, validation, doctrine, annotations, entity

I need some advices or experiences in integrating custom annotations for Doctrine generated entities, but I also want to keep native Doctrine annotations so that they can be somehow registered together.

I have succesfully integrated Doctrine in my ZF application and tested it.

Now I want to have some validations inside my entites. I don't want to write any code in my entities or modify setters. I googled for suggestions and there are some libraries that do the job. Those libraries also provide the ability to return Doctrine entities objects as array (toArray()).

I tried to integrate one of those called Spiffy Library (https://github.com/SpiffyJr/Spiffy). Homepage http://www.spiffyjr.me/.
I followed instructions on that page to include it in my project but no luck. Any help on these would be so appreciated.

Guess I didn't setup correctly AnnotationReader. However I did AnnotationRegistry-ed some of files from Spiffy library (spiffy\Doctrine\Annotations\Validators).
Also gave Spiffy Abstract library my entity manager from ZF registry.

I can also paste some of my code here if neccessary.

Thnaks in advance.